# Saving drop down list value and set selected index after postback

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

I have a small page with 3 drop down list and text box.
my goal is to select a value in every one of the drop down boxes (or any combination) and after post back to set the selected value with the value from last search.
one of the problems  is that 1. after every select in IE the page is doing post back(obviously)
and even when a added the attribute for enable view state the drop down list does not retain the selected value.

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="QSerch.aspx.cs" Inherits="QSerch"
    EnableViewState="true" EnableEventValidation="true" EnableViewStateMac="true"%>

<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .ddlstl
        {
            font-size: 13px;
            font-family: Arial;
        }
        #Iframe1
        {
            height: 700px;
            width: 540px;
        }
        .style2
        {
            width: 243px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body dir="rtl">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" enableviewstate="true">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableScriptGlobalization="True"
        EnablePartialRendering="true" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="false" ScriptMode="Release">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div style="float: right; width: 28px;">
        &nbsp;</div>
    <div style="text-align: right; float: right;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 170px;">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMec" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="ddlstl"
                                    Height="22px" Width="160px" EnableViewState="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMec_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 20px;">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTMec" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="ddlstl"
                                    Height="22px" Width="160px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTMec_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                    EnableViewState="true">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="-1">בחר תפקיד</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 170px;">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlArea" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="ddlstl"
                                    DataSourceID="adsArea" DataTextField="name_area" DataValueField="id_area" Height="22px"
                                    Width="160px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlArea_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                                    EnableViewState="true">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="בחר איזור"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:AccessDataSource ID="adsArea" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/Adam.mdb"
                                    SelectCommand="SELECT [id_area], [name_area] FROM [table_area] ORDER BY [name_area]">
                                </asp:AccessDataSource>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text="חיפוש חופשי" ID="txtFreeText" Style="font-size: 12px;
                                    height: 15px; width: 151px" />
                                <%--<input type="text" value="חיפוש חופשי" onfocus="deleteFreeText()" id="FreeText" name="FreeText"
                                            style="font-size: 12px; height: 15px; width: 151px" runat="server" />--%>
                                <br />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" RenderMode="Inline" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <iframe id="Iframe1" runat="server" frameborder="0" name="Iframe1" scrolling="no"
                                width="360px" src="" style="overflow: auto"></iframe>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)FindControl("txtFreeText");
        tb.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "this.value = ''");
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadProffesion();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First two dropdowns, (id=ddlMec & id=ddlTMec) doesnt have any data asoociated to it. hope it will be dat bound during page load.

Assuming that you must be having problems with the 3rd dropdown, (id:ddlArea) it could be due to the fact that you are using datasource control to bind data. so everytime when page loads, it repopulates data and the selected item is lost.

To tideover this issue, please try binding the dropdownlist on page load and prevent overwriting by controlling it with the help of Page.IsPostBacK property.

Comment: all of the drop down lists where bound in the way of the 3rd. i changed it to server side and i load the first drop down list in the  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadProffesion();
        } and the 2nd drop down load after selected index change of the first so i am trying to handle this and then i will transfer the 3rd drop down list to server side

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the AutoPostBack="True" from  tag.

there is no need of AutoPostBack for DropDownList.

Comment: But then the OnSelectedIndexChange is not firing

Comment: danny you confused me too but because of you i learned new things.... you should have to learn "Post back event Processing sequence" first from http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/aa051705a.htm. by this you would definitely find that you have to avoid adding the ListItem at page because of Post back Event processing. to achieve your goal assign ListItem individually or datasource to dropdown in .cs file and in if(!Page.isPostBack) condition. hope this will help you.

Comment: That didn`t help because i am doing every thing in order and still it is not working. i am thinking about doing it in javascript

Comment: although it can also be done without javascript. but for the best result without involving the server the javascript will be the best.

Comment: I have turned to javascript and gave up on the server side

Comment: I solved it by creating cookie in javascript, i don't know very well js but i got it and it is working like a charm.